# Dynamically Subscribing to Events in RhinoMocks

Tags: c#, events, rhino-mocks

We're currently migrating from NMock2 to RhinoMocks and we're having trouble replicating this code:

```
foreach (EventInfo e in typeof(MarketMapPopupIMVPView).GetEvents())
    Expect.Once.On(mockView).EventAdd(e.Name, new TypeMatcher(typeof(EventHandler)));
```

Essentially this was placed inside a template for MVC controls to ensure that developers using the template were actually wiring up events in the Presenter that were listed in the View. The problem is that we don't know the events before-hand and place the expectation by name which we can't seem to find a way to do in RhinoMocks.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. (I tried to assert a call to e.AddEventListener, and then to dynamically build an action with expression trees to be passed to AssertWasCalled, but neither worked.) Consider that you actually should be testing what the event handler does when the event is raised, not merely that it was wired up. You can't really do that without knowing the event.

Comment: Yeah, this was just something free we gained with NMock by placing it inside some of our templates to ensure developers were actually wiring up their events.

It's not too a big a deal fortunately but it would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done some stuff like this in the past, but determined in most cases it's just not worth it.  Writing your own stub will take less time and effort and be more expressive and understandable.  I wrote a post about it.  This might help.

http://blog.coreycoogan.com/2009/11/11/event-mocking-without-rhino-mocks/